# No module named 'test_cython'

Tags: cython, python-3.7

I am trying to use Cython to convert my python script to a .c file.

I have the following files:

- test_cython.pyx

```
print("Hello Cython")
```

- setup.py

```
import distutils.core
import Cython.Build

distutils.core.setup(
    ext_modules = Cython.Build.cythonize("test_cython.pyx"))
```

This creates the "test_cython.c" using

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

like I want it to, however when I subsequently try to import the test_cython it says that there is no module named test_cython. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have asked a question and got an answer, which explains your problem. Accept the answer if it worked for you and/or ask another question if you have another problem. Don't change your question making the answer/work of others obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to name your package!

```py
import distutils.core
import Cython.Build

distutils.core.setup(
    name='test_cython',
    ext_modules = Cython.Build.cythonize("test_cython.pyx"))
```